# Is it possible to simplify my attempt on the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus into one-case proof?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, proof-verification

I'm trying to prove the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus:

> Let $I=[\alpha, \beta] \subseteq \mathbb R$, $E$ be a Banach space, and $\mathcal S(I,E)$ the space of jump continuous functions from $I$ to $E$. Suppose that $f \in \mathcal S(I,E)$ is continuous at $a \in\mathring I$. Then $$F: I \rightarrow E, \quad x \mapsto \int_{\alpha}^{x} f(\xi) \, d \xi$$ is differentiable at $a$ and $F'(a) = f(a)$.

Because the sign of the integral $\int_a^b$ depends on $a<b$, $a=b$, or $a>b$. I divide the proof into 2 cases, i.e $h>0$ and $h<0$.

**My question:** Is my way of dividing into such two cases necessary or it can be simplified into just one case? Thank you so much for your help!

---

**My attempt:**

We have $$\begin{aligned}\frac{F(a+h)-F(a) -f(a)h}{h} &=\frac{1}{h}\left(\int_{\alpha}^{a+h} f(\xi) \, d \xi-\int_{\alpha}^{a} f(\xi) \, d \xi -f(a)h \right)\\ &=\frac{1}{h}\left(\int_{\alpha}^{a+h} f(\xi) \, d \xi-\int_{\alpha}^{a} f(\xi) \, d \xi - \int_a^{a+h} f(a) \, d \xi \right) \\ &= \frac{1}{h} \int_{a}^{a+h} (f(\xi) -f(a)) \, d \xi \end{aligned}$$

It follows from $f$ is continuous at $a$ that, for all $\delta > 0$, there exists $\epsilon>0$ such that $\xi \in \mathbb B_I(a,\epsilon)$ implies $\|f(\xi) - f(a) \| < \delta$.

**Case 1:** For all $h$ such that $0 <h<\epsilon$, we have $$\begin{aligned}\left\|\frac{F(a+h)-F(a) -f(a)h}{h} \right\| &= \left \| \frac{1}{h} \int_{a}^{a+h} (f(\xi) -f(a)) \, d \xi\right\| \\ &\le \frac{1}{h}  \int_{a}^{a+h} \left \| f(\xi) -f(a) \right\| d \xi \\ & \le \frac{1}{h} \int_{a}^{a+h} \delta\, d \xi =\delta \end{aligned}$$

Because $\delta$ becomes smaller and smaller as $h \to 0^+$, we get $$\lim_{h \to 0^+} \left\|\frac{F(a+h)-F(a) -f(a)h}{h} \right\| = 0$$

**Case 2:** For all $h$ such that $-\epsilon <h <0$, we have $$\begin{aligned}\left\|\frac{F(a+h)-F(a) -f(a)h}{h} \right\| &= \left \| \frac{1}{h} \int_{a}^{a+h} (f(\xi) -f(a)) \, d \xi\right\| \\ &=\left \| \frac{1}{h} \int_{a+h}^{a} -(f(\xi) -f(a)) \, d \xi\right\|\\ &\le \frac{1}{-h}  \int_{a+h}^{a} \left \| f(\xi) -f(a) \right\| d \xi \\ & \le \frac{1}{-h} \int_{a+h}^{a} \delta\, d \xi =\delta \end{aligned}$$

Because $\delta$ becomes smaller and smaller as $h \to 0^-$, we get $$\lim_{h \to 0^-} \left\|\frac{F(a+h)-F(a) -f(a)h}{h} \right\| = 0$$

Finally, we get $$\lim_{h \to 0} \left\|\frac{F(a+h)-F(a) -f(a)h}{h} \right\| = 0$$

As such, $F'(a) = f(a)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not necessary to split it into two cases, you can treat both at once:
\begin{align}
\biggl\lVert \frac{1}{h}\int_a^{a+h} f(\xi) - f(a)\,d\xi\biggr\rVert
&\leqslant \frac{1}{\lvert h\rvert} \int_{\min \{a,a+h\}}^{\max \{a, a+h\}} \lVert f(\xi) - f(a)\rVert\,d\xi \\
&\leqslant \frac{1}{\lvert h\rvert} \int_{\min \{a,a+h\}}^{\max \{a, a+h\}} \delta\,d\xi \\
&= \delta\,.
\end{align}
Whether that is actually a simplification/an improvement …

It is at least a shortening. There's that.

Comment: That's really elegant and saves a lot of effort :) Thank you so much for enlightening me :)

Comment: I have not seen any approach like yours before.